# Prove that given a triangle satisfying $8\prod \sin\frac{A}{2}=\prod \cos(A-B)$ then that triangle is equilateral.

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that given a triangle $ABC$ satisfying $$8 \sin\frac{A}{2}\sin\frac{B}{2}\sin\frac{C}{2} = \cos(A-B)\cos(B-C)\cos(C-A)$$ then that triangle is equilateral.

Comment: Suggest you re-word the question to something like "prove that given a triangle satisfying (your equation) then that triangle is equilateral." In your question you already have said it holds for equilaterals, but it seems you want it to hold *only* for equilaterals.

Comment: @LzuTao, Hi Lzu. I did not receive any notification. I just accidently found this question.

Comment: Just adding that, you have two equations with three variables. Equilateral triangle might not be the only solution.

Comment: Have a look at the infinite solutions: [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=8*Cos[A%2F2]*Cos[B%2F2]*Cos[%28Pi-A-B%29%2F2]-Cos[A-B]*Cos[B-%28Pi-A-B%29]*Cos[%28Pi-A-B%29-A])

Comment: Guess: expand the RHS? What's the rule for cosines, cos(A+B) = cosAcosB - sinAsinB?

Answer (score 2):

Let $p(a,b,c)$ be the left side of your equation, and $q(a,b,c)$ be the right side, using lower case for your $A,B,C$ for no real reason. The equation is then saying that $h(a,b,c)=0$ where $h(a,b,c)=p(a,b,c)-q(a,b,c).$

Now if $a+b<\pi$ we can get a legal triangle with angles $a,b,\pi-a-b.$ Define $w(a,b)=h(a,b,\pi-a-b),$ then if your equation were to hold only for equilateral triangles, we could have $w(a,b)=0$ only for $a=b=\pi/3.$ However for example $w(0.1,0.2)=-0.7648<0$ while $w(1.1,0.2)=0.3647>0.$ This means from the intermediate value theorem there is some $c$ between $0.1$ and $1.1$ for which $w(c,0.2)=0.$ However this $c$ is not $\pi/3$ [or rather more simply, $0.2 \neq \pi/3$] so that there are triangles not equilateral which satisfy your equation.